# C# API GetResponse issue

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm quite new to c# and I'm having an issue when trying to call an API to post some CSV data using the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myurl");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Api-Key:" + apiKey);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Api-Secret:" + apiSecret);
        request.ContentType = "text/csv";

        using (StreamWriter swCSVData = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            StreamReader csvReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\Test\\conf-ato-sprmbrinfo-batch-001.csv"));
            while (!csvReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                swCSVData.WriteLine(csvReader.ReadLine());
            }
            csvReader.Close();
        }
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting response....");
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Got response....");

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
             if (responseStream != null)
             {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(strResponseValue);
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\Test\\apioutput.txt",strResponseValue);
        }
        catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            strResponseValue = "{\"errorMessages\":[\"" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
        }
```

If I run this code using the post test  at ptsv2.com, then I can see that the api call looks like I would expect and I get a response. However, when I change my code to point to my required URL it seems to just hang on the following line:

`response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Does anyone have any idea as to why this could be happening?

Also happy for any recommendations to make my code better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long does it hang there for? How large is the CSV file?

Comment: The CSV file is 1 row so nothing at all. A little over 1k characters in total. I think I left it for at least 5 minutes or so but I guess I expected the response to be fairly instant.

Comment: try to use `using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) { // your code here}` instead of just `response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Comment: and remove this line from your code `HttpWebResponse response = null;
`

Comment: That doesn't seem to have helped. Process has been running for over 2 minutes so far but I will wait a while to see if it returns something. Could my code be an issue if the response format is JSON?

Comment: You don't eventually get an Exception? What version of the .Net framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using v4.5.2. I'm not getting any error at all which is what is so strange. It'll just appear to sit there whilst it waits for the response, but I am starting to wonder if this is an environmental issue on my side which I'm investigating. Maybe my machine cannot get the response due to some communication type issue.

Comment: Just a small note to this...I downloaded VS Code and then used the Rest Client extension to successfully get a response from my target url, so the issue appears to be in my code above or something within VS.

Comment: Ok it turns out I am getting an exception when I make the request:
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on send."
Has anyone come across this type of error before?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a security issue once I could see the exception being returned. I had to add the following line of code for my request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Thanks to the people who took the time to comment on my original question.